# change values in array based on other array js

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Hello I am struggling to edit some values in an array based on an other array, I have this:

```
tags = [
  { name: 'Music', value: 1, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Sport', value: 2, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Games', value: 3, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Animals', value: 4, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Party', value: 5, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Arts', value: 6, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Movies', value: 7, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Travels', value: 8, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Cooking', value: 9, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Dance', value: 10, actif: 0 }
]
person = [
  { idui: 7619, iduser: 101, interest: 5 },
  { idui: 7620, iduser: 101, interest: 3 },
  { idui: 7621, iduser: 101, interest: 4 },
  { idui: 7622, iduser: 101, interest: 1 },
  { idui: 7623, iduser: 101, interest: 2 }
]
```

I would like to set tags.actif to 1 if person.interest == tags.value. I guess I will have to use every of find but I don't really know how to succeed with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each object in the tags array to a new object with the updated `actif` value if their is a person with the same interest as the tag value. You can find this by using the [array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method

```js
const tags = [
  { name: 'Music', value: 1, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Sport', value: 2, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Games', value: 3, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Animals', value: 4, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Party', value: 5, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Arts', value: 6, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Movies', value: 7, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Travels', value: 8, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Cooking', value: 9, actif: 0 },
  { name: 'Dance', value: 10, actif: 0 },
];

const persons = [
  { idui: 7619, iduser: 101, interest: 5 },
  { idui: 7620, iduser: 101, interest: 3 },
  { idui: 7621, iduser: 101, interest: 4 },
  { idui: 7622, iduser: 101, interest: 1 },
  { idui: 7623, iduser: 101, interest: 2 },
];

const changed = tags.map((tag) => {
  const person = persons.find(({ interest }) => interest === tag.value);
  
  return person ? {...tag, actif: 1} : tag;
});

console.log(changed);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;}
```